# Is it important to mark spoiler questions as such?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, spoilers

Since most of the questions here are going to be about films, television series and novels, perhaps it would be a good idea to mark spoiler questions with [Spoiler], or a spoiler tag?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a spoiler syntax that we have added to the site's markdown already.

You use it by prefixing your writing with `>!` which will produce:

> SPOILED TEXT!

The text will show on mouse-over.

Comment: That's great. Many people will not be aware of this, however, and many more might not be inclined to mark their question/answer as a spoiler. I don't think this should fall on the shoulders of diamond moderators.

Comment: I can ask ... i think it was gaming that made the original request how they handled education.

Comment: +1 for really good idea.  Maybe put it in the title so one can see it from *Questions* page.  This is a necessity, IMO.

Comment: I would say that mouse-over is too easy to trigger by accident, and it does not gives a clue what is it for a newbie user. What about <<Spoiler!>> button that expands into hidden text?

Comment: I've used the spoiler tag, and it seems like it's working just fine so far, so...

Comment: I like the spoiler markup... but sadly it does not work in Safari on the iPad or iPhone!

Answer (score 7):

The [spoiler](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoiler) tag is a meta fluffy used to define the type of query and nothing to do with the content of the question.

Tags should help summarise what the question is about and not about what the question may appear to be.

It's noise that shouldn't be proliferating as much as it is since it's like tagging a question with [subjective](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjective).

It's all going to be a spoiler to somebody no matter how much you try and mindcheck people before they hit the site.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to remove the [spoiler] tag, and blacklist it. I agree with Eight and Morganpdx that the tag is really just noise. And it also can be potentially harmful if users block that tag, because they don't want to be spoiled on topic A, and thus do not see a question on topic B that they are an expert on.

Actually, I'll blacklist it as soon as I find someone who knows how to do that.

It is done

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @eight, the spoiler tag identifies the *type* of question, or more specifically the *possible type* of answer, and not what the question is *about*.

I also think more use of the "Spoiler" markup would be awesome.