# Should spoilers questions have a spoiler tag, spolier notice in the title or something else?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it important to mark spoiler questions as such?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-it-important-to-mark-spoiler-questions-as-such)

I want to have an official policy for denoting spoiler questions, that way all the spoiler questions can use the same method to denote that their spoiler status.

As is, people just choose at random how to denote that their question is a spoiler.

What is the single best way to denote that a question is a spoiler question?

Answer (score 1):

- Phrase the question title so ther's no spoiler in it.
- Use the "> !" Markup to hide any Spoilers.

> The answer is 42!

If this is done, we dont need any spoiler tag or spolier notice in the title

---

**Edit:**

**If the Spoiler in the title cannot be avoid**, then the spoiler tag could be used as they specify itin the [Gaming.SE spoiler Tag Wiki](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoiler)

> This tag should only used for questions which contain spoilers in the title, such as "How do I kill GLaDOS?" [...]

[Why did Douglas Adams pick 42 as the ultimate answer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/310/why-did-douglas-adams-pick-42-as-the-ultimate-answer) is a great example of question that cannot avoid it.

Comment: Note that in question listings, if the spoiler markup is part of the body excerpt, it will be shown in plaintext.

Comment: @Rebecca Chernoff : In the world where I live, we call that a Bug. Would it be corrected?

Comment: it isn't a bug.  Markdown syntax is stripped from the listings, such as on http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @Rebecca Chernoff I see: it's not a bug; it's a feature (sigh).