# Do we have any sort of spoiler policy?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it important to mark spoiler questions as such?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-it-important-to-mark-spoiler-questions-as-such)

After seeing [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2467/why-did-rush-do-what-he-did-at-the-end-of-sg-u-s02e12), which was posted the day after the episode in question aired, I wanted to know if we have any official timelines for spoilers?  Obviously discussions about something like Back to the Future, which came out over a decade ago shouldn't be spoilered.  But, what about the recent Battlestar Galactica?  Has enough time passed that we shouldn't ask questions with spoilers in them and spoiler markdown questions?  Where's the line?

Comment: In general, if someone who hasn't seen it will feel spoiled by it, you should cover it up with the spoiler markdown and keep it out of the title.