# How do you add spoiler markup to posts?

Tags: support, spoilers, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I be indicating a question is by it's very asking, a spoiler?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1514/how-should-i-be-indicating-a-question-is-by-its-very-asking-a-spoiler)

I'm missing something obvious. How do you add spoiler markup to posts? I'm sure it's something ridiculously simple but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start a paragraph with >!

For example:

> This is a spoiler.

If you click 'edit' on this answer, you can see it in action next to the text I typed to make this.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.