# Why do you have to mouse-over to see content in a quote?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I am having a problem that I need to mouse-over a quote to see it. Is this a bug or intentional?

See in this link, I need to mouse-over "Royal Canadian Bandit" quotes to see them.
[Why does Poe Dameron leave Jakku without BB-8?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111680/why-does-poe-dameron-leave-jakku-without-bb-8?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's called **spoilertagging**.

People use it to mark content that could be seen as spoilers. E.g. in the answer you link to, people who haven't seen *The Force Awakens* might not want to mouse over those sections of the text and learn what happens in the film.

See also the various [spoilers](/questions/tagged/spoilers) posts on meta, e.g. [How should I be indicating a question is, by its very asking, a spoiler?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1514/how-should-i-be-indicating-a-question-is-by-its-very-asking-a-spoiler) and [What is the policy for spoilers?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-policy-for-spoilers?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks, intentional then. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Because those are spoiler tags, not regular quotes.

If you look at the markdown of that post (by clicking the "edit" button) you'll see that Royal Canadian Bandit was using `>!` instead of `>`.

Comment: Thanks, intentional then. Cheers.