# Where can I request feedback on a potentially spoiler-filled question?

Tags: discussion, spoilers, etiquette

I have a question about the ending of *Spider-Man: Homecoming* which seems near-impossible to ask without spoilers. ([*See **spoiler**-filled question here*](https://gist.github.com/Stevoisiak/18cfcd6fc38ba99ef380b3c858e909c7))

After reading the guidelines from *[How should I be indicating a question is, by its very asking, a spoiler?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1514/79413)* I believe I have sufficiently edited the question's body to hide any spoilers.

However, I am struggling to come up with a question title which is vague enough to avoid spoiling the film, but descriptive enough for potential readers.

**Where can I request feedback on a question which contains spoilers in the title?**

If there isn't already a place for requesting question feedback, could one be created? It could take inspiration from the [*Sandbox for Proposed Challenges*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) on Meta Code Golf.

Comment: I took a look at it. Apart from the title, what you're asking appears to have been left intentionally vague at the end of the film (which I haven't seen). In this case it may fall under our [future works policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite "Spide-Mman"? :-) I think you just fell foul of [Muphry's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry%27s_law).

Comment: @Randal'Thor: oh dearie me, I fell right into it there.

Answer (score 2):

Although this specific case as @Gallifreyan says is off-topic due to our future works policy, this can apply to other people looking for feedback on their questions.

#### [TREU](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/)

If you have above 20 rep, you can join our chatroom, [The Restaurant at the End of the Universe (TREU)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/). Anyone in there would happily discuss your question and help you figure out a way to remove some spoilers or hide certain bits.

In the worst case. You can always provide the question as is and one of our helpful editors will come round and hide/help hide any obvious spoilers. Our only rule is to keep spoilers out of titles.

Comment: There are two related question already asked here [1st](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163498/on-pepper-potts-and-tony-starks-relationship) and [2nd](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166693/what-did-tony-stark-say-to-the-press)

Comment: @JonSnow that's very interesting but what does that have to do with people getting feedback for spoiler-filled questions? Also the 2nd related question is the one in question

Comment: It was reply to "off-topic due to our future works policy" part, which is but vague form your answer.

Comment: Asking in chat is fine but as per my experience in SE chat, people don't react well with spoilers

Comment: @JonSnow What? They wouldn't react well if you just said "Vader is Luke's father" but if you're trying to figure out a way to hide spoilers you're going to come in with a warning about the spoiler-y nature of your discussion and if they don't like it they can suggest a channel for you to go to. There definitely was one chatroom that would've been happy to help. Although that's been ripped from our grip now.