# What's the bench mark for spoilerification?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a moratorium on some spoilers?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1561/is-there-a-moratorium-on-some-spoilers)

How long should we wait before not spoiler tagging sections of questions?