# Character Death Spoilers In Title

Tags: discussion, spoilers, title

Very similar to [this unanswered meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/835/is-it-okay-to-have-spoilers-in-question-titles).  Should we allow the obfuscating a character's name when the question is about his/her/its death?  In particular, [this question about Merlin (BBC)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87339/after-arthurs-death-why-does-merlin-not-return-to-camelot) was originally titled:

> After this character's death, why does Merlin not return?

To me, this is acceptable and proper.  I would know not to go into that question, because I have not seen all of the episodes yet.

[This question about Supernatural](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72451/is-there-any-evidence-that-this-character-is-really-dead) was edited to remove the spoiler from the title.

[This question about the Hunger Games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8993/why-was-a-certain-character-in-the-hunger-games-killed) was framed this way, and went unedited.

[This question about Ender's Game](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/how-did-ender-kill-this-character) was also framed this way, and not edited.

Lastly, [this question about Harry Potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/how-was-was-a-certain-character-killed-without-avada-kedavra-spoilers) originally contained the character's name, but was later changed to use the generic "this character" phrasing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [original spoiler guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/968/5184) established on meta stated

> - **Avoid spoilers completely in the title.  This doesn't mean using [REDACTED] or silly things like that, it means coming up with another way to summarise the question.**
> - Avoid spoilers in the first chunk of the question, because this text is often included (even if it is in spoiler tags) in links to the question.
> - Don't use "SPOILER" in the title.  Exactly what a spoiler is is subjective, and IMO it's just ugly.
> - As with answers, put as little text into the spoiler markup as possible, consider how "spoiled" I would feel, and don't consider the age of the material.
> - Don't include anything superfluous if it's remotely spoiler-y.  Rework the question text so that you get the question across without including spoilers that don't need to be there.
> - If unsure, use the tag or avoid the spoiler altogether (there are places, e.g. RSS, where the spoiler markup is ignored).  I want users to be able to follow tags or even the whole questions list without having to worry about users in another country getting access to their favourite TV show first and spoiling episodes for them.

The top voted/accepted answer on last year's [To spoiler or not to spoiler, June 2014 edition](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4732/5184) referred to that post and quoted the same guidelines.

Both went largely uncontested.

I see no reason to believe that the community consensus has changed to the point that the accepted policy should be modified.

That said - we, as a community, could be a lot more considerate about spoilers.