# What's our Spoiler policy?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, spoilers

As I have a great reputation for not hiding spoilers, I want to know Spoiler policy of this site.

This question [What is the policy for spoilers?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-policy-for-spoilers) is asking about formatting. I want to know what should be considered spoilers?

Technically, Star Trek: TOS can be spoiler for someone who hasn't watched it. But, it is accepted here without spoiler markup. Why?

Newly launched books, movies, TV shows etc based questions contain major spoilers. But, for how long it'd be considered *New*?

If we don't already have policies, let's make it and put it in FAQ.

Comment: I disagree that _[What is the Policy for Spoilers?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-policy-for-spoilers)_ is about formatting; both the question and the answers are about what are considered spoilers.

Comment: I agree with @SQB. The top-voted answer to the linked question (+10, -0) is rather clear. Avoid spoilers in titles and in first paragraphs. Avoid spoilers at all unless they're the *point* of your question or answer. Use the tag as little as possible, as necessary.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan And, this isn't what I am asking if you can read the question.

Comment: Second point from the top answer: _"Consider how "spoiled" I would feel if I knew the information in advance. This is extremely subjective, but it's important, ***because otherwise everything is a spoiler***."_ (emphasis mine). There's your answer.

Comment: Perhaps your title will be clearer as "What is considered spoilers".

Comment: In addition to the *What is the Policy for Spoilers* question, we also have [Is there a moratorium on some spoilers?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1561/is-there-a-moratorium-on-some-spoilers) which may be a more exact match to your concerns.

Comment: Tony Meyer's answer on the *Policy* question directly address the complaints people have had about your recent spoilers.