# What's the policy on whole-question spoilers?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

Related:  [What's the policy on whole-answer spoilers?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6673/13418)

[This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/87329/13418) question is totally legitimate. But the whole body of the question is in spoiler tag. It is not the first time I see a question almost entirely in spoiler tags. And it just seems weird.

I realize that a movie question is different from a book, comics or series question: you either saw the movie or you didn't; whereas you could have watched a series up until season X and ask a legitimate season X-1 question and at the end of the question, in spoiler tag, say something along "now we know that it may have been for this reason which we learned later, but can you enlighten this particular point?"

But fully spoiler tagged question give me the feeling of unnecessary work. The name of the movie in the title of the question should be sufficient to prevent people who didn't see the movie from clicking the question, should it not ?

Comment: *“The name of the movie in the title of the question should be sufficient to prevent people who didn't see the movie from clicking the question”* That, and tagging the question with the name of the movie – e.g. [tag:age-of-ultron], [tag:the-force-awakens] – then people can filter it in the question list if they’d like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spoilers need to have some context around them, so you know what is spoiled by the spoiler block.  In addition, you should make the question accessible by having something outside of the spoiler block. Throw in some non-spoilery context for the question, or something so people can get some idea what the question is about before they look at the spoiler blocks.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a guideline: if you can imagine filling the hidden part with a completely different, reasonable question, then you're overusing spoiler markup. Otherwise, even someone who doesn't want to see spoilers has to read the hidden content in order to find out whether the question was about something they didn't want to be spoiled about.

In the specific case of [What is the “Water of Sight” featured in Avengers: Age of Ultron?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87329/what-is-this-plot-device-featured-in-avengers-age-of-ultron), the whole point of the question is “Water of Sight” (whatever that is, I'm not familiar with that movie or the material it's based on). So the question should mention “Water of Sight” prominently, in fact that should be the title of the question: *What is the Water of Sight in Avengers: Age of Ultron?*

Is it a major plot point that Water of Sight appears in this movie? The details of how it appears and what its role is, maybe. But the fact that it appears at all? I doubt it, and even if it is, since it's the whole point of the question, you can't hide it without making it impossible to tell what the question is about.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But what is your conclusion ? Yes it's normal ? It happens, it's frustrating but it's necessary ? Should we do something about it ?

Comment: I'm outlining (a part of) a spoiler usage policy. If a question goes over the line, [edit it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/87329/revisions).