# Why is my question closed?

Tags: support, closed-questions, moderators

After moderator and users trying to close it, it got reopened by the sane.

[In Star Wars: "The Force Awakens," how could this lightsaber have turned up where it did?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111121/in-star-wars-the-force-awakens-how-could-this-item-have-turned-up-in-this-lo)

Why has it been put on hold?

If it's the title, then users need to realize that the way we get more users here is to have good titles that get lots of hits on google. If you put why did generic generic generic, not only will it not come up on google hits but users here won't be interested in checking out the question.

How do I get it taken off of hold?

Comment: It's not closed, it's locked until the dispute is resolved. Also, calm down!

Comment: (For the record, I agree with your stance on question titles. But you are going to win some, lose some. Don't get too frustrated.)

Comment: there is a way to phrase a meaningful title without also giving away key plot elements to a movie less than 2 weeks old.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield [ahem](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7794/31394)

Comment: @Dvk 'Non-fixable'? Any mod can unlock it, and would if the title JMFB desires doesn't violate policy.  Policy can be easily changed by regular users via participation in Meta. And the lock is set to expire after a week as well (which is 18 hours from this writing).

Answer (score 6):

Right now **it isn't closed**. (Incidentally moderators weren't involved either in closing or reopening it; that was just ordinary users like you and me.)

What's been done to it now is a 'lock', which means nobody can edit it or vote on it until it's unlocked. This was done by moderator Keen. Obviously he's the only one who can explain exactly why he did it, but the notice "Content dispute" which he added at the same time suggests that he locked it **because there was significant disagreement between yourself and some others about its content**. Frequent edits and rollbacks often lead to such a lock being imposed.

You're quite right to take this to meta, as (I believe) this is the appropriate place to hash out disagreements that led to a post being locked. I'm not sure why everyone is downvoting you here.

(FWIW, I have no 'axe to grind' in this issue. I didn't answer the question or vote to close or reopen it, although I may have voted to "Leave Open" when it first appeared in the Close Votes review queue.)

Answer (score 5):

I locked it to prevent you from rolling back the edits that remove spoilers from the question title. You've made it clear you'll do so multiple times, so I put a stop to it.

If you want to put spoilers in question titles, then post [on Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-policy-for-spoilers) with an argument for it, and garner enough votes to change our policy.

Comment: Re your second paragraph, how about [this Meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/will-we-ever-clean-up-those-ridiculous-spoiler-free-the-force-awakens-question)?

Answer (score 2):

For the record, search results **are not returned by title alone**. The entire body of the question is indexed.

If you put your spoilers in a spoiler tag in the question body, Google will find it just fine. Googling ["luke's lightsaber maz"](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=luke%27s+lightsaber+maz) turns up [this duped question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111023/how-did-maz-kanata-acquire-this-weapon) as the 2nd result.

That duplicate question immediately links to your own question.

In other words, SEO isn't relevant to this discussion, and the title should follow our spoiler policies. Willfully, repeatedly ignoring meta policies is a good reason to have a post locked.