# Is it possible to update the "How to Ask" block to include our policy on spoilers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When reviewing a [recent question about *Westworld*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152412/why-does-this-character-commit-suicide-in-westworld), I encountered what turned out to be a [spoiler to climax of the season](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35373904#35373904).

Our [accepted policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-policy-for-spoilers) on spoilers in titles seems to be **"try not to"**, especially about spoiling the *friggin season ending*. However, new users have no way of knowing this, so we end up with [spoilers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/152412/1).

Surely we have vigilant <s>geeks</s> <s>fanatics</s> <s>pedants</s> editors who will hopefully catch those things before some time elapses, but once a cat is out of the bag, it just is. There's also the chat feed, which does not update itself when the question is paraphrased.

This brings us to my request: **update the** [**"How to Ask" block**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pox3m.png) on the main site (and the relevant Help page) **to reflect our policy on spoilers**.

To be clear, I'm not trying to convince myself that everyone will read this block, let alone follow the policy; still, it's a nice <s>useless</s> precaution to have.

Comment: We can update it, but you need to be very aware that no-one reads it, certainly not before asking their first few questions.

Comment: @Valorum  -  true, but then I will have an iron-clad reason to DV *every* new question without feeling guilty.

Comment: I try to avoid feeling *anything* when closing/DV'ing questions. I find it helps to look at questions/answers objectively, without fear or favour.

Comment: @Valorum  -  I meant the guilt of not explaining the rules to newcomers. With the updated block it'd be like *"should've read that bit set in font size 3 on the bottom of the page"*. Also, it's sad, but it appears we need a [higher authority](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259914/what-parts-of-the-help-center-can-site-moderators-edit) to change that block.

Comment: Is it possible? Of course it is. Is it pointful? Of course it isn't.

Comment: For the record, the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page in the help centre is mod-editable, but the "how to ask" box and the [How do I ask a good question?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page aren't, though at least the former, and probably the latter too, are editable by SE employees.

Comment: @Randal'Thor should I have asked this tagged with [discussion] first?

Comment: @Gallifreyan Meh, which tag you choose doesn't matter *that* much on meta. But for the sake of pedantry, yes, it should probably be tagged both [meta-tag:discussion] ("should the How to Ask block include something about spoilers?") and [meta-tag:feature-request] ("if so, please implement this").

Comment: @Randal'Thor how about [featured]? :P *feeling lucky*

Comment: What about where it says "What's your science fiction or fantasy question? Be specific."? Could we make that say "What's your science fiction or fantasy question? Be specific and avoid spoilers (for more guidance, see the help center)." or something like that?