# How far back should spoilers be marked for the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

Marvel titles are coming out quite frequently these days; between movies and shows, content is moving very quickly. How far back should we mark spoilers on content? Is there a standard of "*x* movies/shows back"? Or is it entirely up to asker and editor discretion?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for this; we've had people insist on spoiler tags on works that are more than 40 years old, which boggles me.  Personally my opinion is that anything that doesn't show up in the title or the first lines is fair game for spoilers; people shouldn't be reading questions about works they don't want spoilered.

Comment: Dupe of [What is the policy for spoilers?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-policy-for-spoilers?rq=1_) notably "***Don't consider the age of the material. There are still people new to Star Wars, the Matrix, and The Lord of the Rings, even though these could all be considered so established that the main points are common knowledge.***"