# Please blacklist the [spoiler] tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-blacklist-request

The [spoiler](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoiler) tag keeps popping onto existence on random questions, even though [it is meaningless](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-it-important-to-mark-spoiler-questions-as-such/248#248) and we [do not advocate its use](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-it-important-to-mark-spoiler-questions-as-such/).

The `spoiler` tag has been [blacklisted on Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/spoiler-alert-spoiler-dies). Let's follow suit. ([I thought we had it blacklisted](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-it-important-to-mark-spoiler-questions-as-such/453#453) but evidently not.)

Please add `spoilers?` to the tag blacklist.

Comment: I distinctly remember asking for it to be blacklisted and getting confirmation that it was.

Answer (score 2):

The current use of this tag, to denote things you should know by now or will know because you're going to read the entire question and hover over all the text because you hate yourself and like to blame others for when you put your hand on the stove while it's on and you're paying more attention to what Kim Kardashian is doing talking to Justin Bieber about sex advice, ruins the content use of tags and makes it another meta case.

It also conflates the issue when someone has a legitimate question about the new *Spoiler* movie and franchise of novels about a young robot who grows up to lead a rebellion against the EMPs.

Comment: geez, spoilers...